# Nuxt dragable slider teleports to mouse position upon re-sliding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, nuxt.js, draggable

I've tried to make a dragabe slider at first glance it seems to work fine.
But upon sliding it more than once you'll notice it bugs out.

It looks like it teleports to the mouse position on the first mousemovement.
I've tried several things but can't wrap my head around it.

My html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper" v-on:mousemove="slide()">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mouseDown: 0,
      start: undefined,
      position: undefined,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    slide() {
      const vm = this
      document.body.onmousedown = function () {
        vm.start = window.event.clientX
        vm.mouseDown = 1
      }
      document.body.onmouseup = function () {
        vm.mouseDown = 0
      }
      if (this.mouseDown == 1) {
        vm.position = window.event.clientX - vm.start
        document.querySelector('.slider').style.left = vm.position + 'px'
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I've recreated a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-dragable-slider?file=pages%2Findex.vue) of my problem.

Comment: Please add code in the question so the question will not lose it's values when stackblitz is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i needed to remember the old reposition before repositioning the slider. To fix this i changed the code as following:

```js
data() {
  return {
    mouseDown: 0,
    start: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    old_pos: 0 // initialize old_pos
  }
},
```

```js
slide() {
  const vm = this
  document.body.onmousedown = function() {
    vm.start = window.event.clientX
    vm.mouseDown = 1
  }
  document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    vm.old_pos = vm.position + vm.old_pos // Sets old_pos when a new position has been set.
    vm.mouseDown = 0
  }
  if(this.mouseDown == 1) {
    vm.position = window.event.clientX - vm.start
    document.querySelector(".slider").style.left = vm.position + vm.old_pos + "px"; // Adds the old position as starting point of movement.
  }
}
```